# Density of zeroes of the Jacobian of an injective function

Tags: derivatives, inverse-function

I'm looking for a kind of reverse result to the Inverse Function Theorem. Let $f:\mathbb{R}^n\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$ be a differentiable injective function. Is it true that points where the Jacobian of $f$ is zero are isolated? If so, then do you know any source for such a result? If it is false, then maybe you know of some other result that says something about zeroes of the Jacobian.

Comment: Consider $f(x,y) = (x^3,y)$. It now occurs to me to ask you: When you say the Jacobian of $f$, are you referring to the matrix or the determinant?

Comment: The determinant. I was expecting a situation like in your counterexample might happen. Is it at least true that Jacobian cannot vanish on a set of positive measure or on an open set? Maybe the set where the Jacobian vanishes is a manifold of dimension smaller than $n$ or a union of such manifolds.

Comment: Definitely cannot vanish on an open set. Consider the rank theorem.